# The main form freezes even though I use a BackgroundWorker and Control.Invoke()

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, invoke

In the following source code, I am loading 20 CSV files (Each CSV file has 1000000 rows and three columns) and drawing 20 plots using ZedGraph.

I am using BackgroundWorker to generate plots.

```
    private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawPlots();
    }

    private void PlotButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        plotButton.Enabled = false;

        MessageBox.Show("Plot generation will start. Press OK");

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
        this.MaximumSize = this.Size;

        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void GeneratePlots()
    {
        //call zedGraphControl1 using Invoke() method
        zedGraphControl1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
        {
            // clear old curves
            zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();

            // style the plot
            zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.Title.Text = "Simulation Data Plot";
            zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Steps";
            zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Energy";
            zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.Legend.FontSpec.Size = 6;

            foreach (CheckBox chkBox in checkBoxList)
            {
                if (chkBox.Checked == true)
                {
                    FileInfo fi = (FileInfo)chkBox.Tag;

                    CsvConfiguration myConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                    {
                        Delimiter = ","
                    };

                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
                    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, myConfig))
                    {
                        List<double> xAxisForSteps = new List<double>();
                        List<double> yAxisForMagnetization = new List<double>();
                        List<double> yAxisForEnergy = new List<double>();

                        if (csv.Read() && csv.ReadHeader())
                        {
                            while (csv.Read())
                            {
                                int step = csv.GetField<int>("Step");
                                double magnetization = csv.GetField<double>("Magnetization");
                                int energy = csv.GetField<int>("Energy");

                                xAxisForSteps.Add(step);
                                yAxisForMagnetization.Add(magnetization);
                                yAxisForEnergy.Add(energy);
                            }

                            // plot the data as curves
                            var curve1 = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.AddCurve(fi.Name, xAxisForSteps.ToArray(), yAxisForEnergy.ToArray(), Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255)));
                            curve1.Line.IsAntiAlias = true;
                            curve1.Symbol.IsVisible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // auto-axis and update the display
                zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.XAxis.ResetAutoScale(zedGraphControl1.GraphPane, CreateGraphics());
                zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.YAxis.ResetAutoScale(zedGraphControl1.GraphPane, CreateGraphics());
                zedGraphControl1.Refresh();

                plotButton.Enabled = true;
            }
        }));
    }
```

This source code was giving the following error:

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' has detected a problem in 
'C:\git\plotting\plotting\bin\Debug\plotting.vshost.exe'.

Additional information: The CLR has been unable to transition from COM 
context 0x10d8088 to COM context 0x10d8140 for 60 seconds. The thread that 
owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non 
pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping 
Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance 
impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or 
memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, 
all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait 
primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages 
during long running operations.
```

So, I switched off the *ContextSwitchDeadlock* from the Debugging Assistant.

The problem is the main form freezes even though I use a `BackgroundWorker` and `Control.Invoke()`.

Are the CheckBoxes creating an issue here?

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You are creating a background thread, then with Invoke, delegating heavy operations to the main thread.

Comment: Your `BackgroundWorker` is pointless. The whole point is that the `DoWork` event is executed on a background thread and the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events are executed on the UI thread. If you just call `Control.Invoke` then that's going back to the UI thread, so basically no multi-threading at all. If you do use `Invoke` then it's not supposed to be for the entire operation. It's supposed to be just for the bits that MUST be done on the UI thread. You're not supposed to call `Invoke` at all with a BGW though. You're supposed to call `ReportProgress`.

Comment: If you want to call `Invoke` at all then you may as well not use a `BackgroundWorker` at all. You'd probably be better off learning how to use `async`/`await` anyway.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, If I remove `Control.Invoke()`, I get this -- *An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code.......Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'zedGraphControl1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.*

Comment: @Flexz, If I remove `Control.Invoke()`, I get this -- *An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code.......Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'zedGraphControl1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.*

Comment: Simply removing the `Invoke` call is not a solution and I never suggested that it was. You need to put some thought into what is supposed to be happening here, which would include reading what I actually posted. The point of a `BackgroundWorker` is to do work in the background. If you call `Invoke` then you're doing work in the foreground. Obviously pointless. You need to do the bulk of your work in the `DoWork` event handler or methods called directly from it. ONLY call `Invoke` if and when you need to update the UI, so only execute the code to update the UI inside it.

Comment: As I also said, if you use a `BackgroundWorker` then you're not supposed to call `Invoke` at all. Avoiding doing so is the very point of the `BackgroundWorker`. You're supposed to call `ReportProgress` and update the UI in the `ProgressChanged` event handler or else handle the `RunWorkerCompleted` event to update the UI when the work is done. If you're going to call `Invoke` then you may as well use a `Thread` or the `ThreadPool` directly. Better yet, learn how to use `async`/`await` and avoid all of that.

Comment: You may find [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?542316-Using-the-BackgroundWorker-Component) enlightening.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, Okay. Thanks. My issue is resolved. :)

Comment: Why do you read out magnetization if you don't plot it at all?

Comment: @Fildor, Yes. That was redundant.